# Push me higher, daddy

Tags: word-usage

[image]

"**Push me higher, daddy.**" my son told me.

He wanted me to push stronger so he can get higher.

What is the approriate word to use. Higher? High? Harder?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *Push me **higher*** in the cited context (as with *Push me **over there***, the highlighted adverbial/adjectival element can be understood as the "goal" - *Push me in such a way that I end up **higher** or **over there***). I'm not exactly sure why *Push it **stronger*** isn't really idiomatic (we'd normally say *Push it [more] **strongly*** or *Push it **harder***). As pointed out, I can't see why you wouldn't want your son to use ***higher*** above, but if you *must* have an alternative, I'd suggest ***harder*** as idiomatically natural.

Comment: "Push me harder so I can **go** higher."

Comment: @Luke Sawczak: Exactly. In my paraphrasing, ***in such a way that = in order that = so.***

Comment: @FumbleFingers I meant to draw attention to "go" instead of "get" in this context.

Comment: How about: _"Pater dear, I desire that you should push me with greater force, so that I might achieve a greater height!"_  ... Nah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Push me **higher**!" is fine.  Children are not always aware of cause and effect, and instead focus on the *result* they want rather than the steps to achieve it.  For example a child might say, "I want **up**!" instead of "Please **pick me up**!"

Of course a more perspicacious child will say, "Push me **harder**!" because that is the action that will lead to the desired result.

A child who is still figuring out the *right* words might say "Push me **stronger**!" but as FumbleFingers mentions in his comment, this is not idiomatic and, at some point, someone will correct it to "push me *harder*".

Comment: Good answer, but note that if anything is wrong with "push me higher", it's extremely subtle. We certainly have similar expressions in which a motion on a recipient changes its location. For example, "lift me higher". With "lift", of course, there's continuous contact, whereas a swing is touch-and-release. But "push" can mean continuous contact ("push the wheelchair") *or* one-time contact ("push him over the edge"). So I'm not quite sold on the idea that "push me higher" glosses over any cause and effect; the cause is the pushing and the effect is "me higher". ;)

Comment: If there is a problem, it's that "push me higher" somehow intuitively sounds like the continuous contact version of "push", which would of course be wrong for what one does to a kid on a swing. But that's the subtle part; I can't put my finger on why it makes me think that.